# Fast LINQ query against List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

suppose you have an big **unsorted** `List<MyClass>` of

```
public class MyClass
{ 
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to search for an item using LINQ. With this simple clause: `where my.Id == id`. Do you recommend something to get the query faster? IComparable?

**Edit:** what I mean is I use normal linq or there is a faster option? for example writing a custom IComparable and binarysearch?

Thanks!

Update: I know a Dictionary is the fastest option with a unique ID.

Comment: If you don't have unique ids, which result do you want to return? The first one that's found?

Comment: Exactly one item or "null, one or more"?

Comment: If the list is unsorted, the best performance you can get is O(n).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use LINQ's FirstOrDefault:

```
 MyClass firstMatch = theList.FirstOrDefault(my => my.Id == id);
```

Without sorting the list, this is probably the best option, even though it's still O(N).

Answer (score 2):

As you stated that your list is unsorted, you can't do anything better than `O(n)` search, for example using `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` as shown in [@Reed Copsey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275036/fast-linq-query-against-listt/7275064#7275064).

In fact binary search works only with sorted data, while is useless in other cases.

Anyway, if you need to access several times to that list to find objects using the `Id`, for sure you will be faster by sorting the list and using binary search (i.e. getting `O(log(n))` access time), or by copying the list to a `Dictionary<>` (i.e. getting `~O(1)` access time).